# Failed to write file when using Spring Integration Sftp to upload files

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I have tried to use `emberstack/sftp` or `atmoz/sftp` to host a sftp server in Docker container for testing purpose.

```yaml
  sftp:
    image: emberstack/sftp
    volumes:
      - ./data/sftp.json:/app/config/sftp.json:ro
      - ./data/sftptest:/home/demo/sftp:rw
    ports:
      - "2222:22"
```

And my project is based on Spring Boot 2.7.4/Kotlin Coroutines/Java17.

I have already defined the following beans for uploading upload the files.

```kotlin
@Confgiuration
class MyConfig{
//other beans.

    @Bean
    fun sftpOutboundFlow(): IntegrationFlow {
        return IntegrationFlows
            .from("toSftpChannel")
            .handle(
                Sftp.outboundAdapter(sftpSessionFactory(), FileExistsMode.FAIL)
                    .useTemporaryFileName(false)
                    .remoteDirectory(sftpProperties.remoteDirectory)
            )
            .get()
    }
}

// a messaging gateway to send file.
@MessagingGateway
interface UploadGateway {
    @Gateway(requestChannel = "toSftpChannel")
    fun upload(file: File)
}
```

The unit test is like this.

```kotlin
@Test
fun `upload ach batch files to sftp`() = runTest {
    val test = File("src/test/resources/foo.txt")
    log.debug("uploading file: $test, ${test.exists()}")
    uploadGateway.upload(test)
    eventually(5.seconds) {
        Paths.get("./data/sftptest/foo.txt").shouldExist()
    }
}
```

The above log debug output shows the uploading file is existed as expected.

I got the following exceptions.

```bash
Error handling message for file [D:\myproject\build\resources\test\foo.txt -> foo.txt]; 
nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: 
Failed to write to '/home/demo/sftp/foo.txt' while uploading the file; nested exception is java.io.IOException: 
failed to write file
org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: 
Error handling message for file [D:\myproject\build\resources\test\foo.txt -> foo.txt]; 
nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: 
Failed to write to '/home/demo/sftp/foo.txt' while uploading the file; 
nested exception is java.io.IOException: 
failed to write file, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=D:\myproject\build\resources\test\foo.txt, 
....

Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to write to '/home/demo/sftp/foo.txt' while uploading the file; nested exception is java.io.IOException: failed to write file
    at app//org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.sendFileToRemoteDirectory(RemoteFileTemplate.java:573)
    at app//org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.doSend(RemoteFileTemplate.java:353)
    ... 143 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: failed to write file
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.write(SftpSession.java:176)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory$CachedSession.write(CachingSessionFactory.java:237)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.doSend(RemoteFileTemplate.java:601)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.sendFileToRemoteDirectory(RemoteFileTemplate.java:570)
    ... 144 more
Caused by: 2: No such file
    at app//com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2873)
    at app//com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._put(ChannelSftp.java:594)
    at app//com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:540)
    at app//com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:492)
    at app//org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.write(SftpSession.java:173)
    ... 147 more
```

**Update**: I created a [sample project](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-puzzles/tree/master/integration-sftp) to produce this issue.

Run the following command to start sftp.

```bash
docker compose up sftp
```

Run test [SftpIntegrationFlowsTest](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-puzzles/blob/master/integration-sftp/src/test/kotlin/com/example/demo/SftpIntegrationFlowsTest.kt) to produce the issue.

Comment: Does the FTP server authenticate successfully?

Comment: The exceptions you posted isn't much to work off of. Can you maybe try to print the inner exceptions (recursively) as well until you have everything and post it here?

Comment: I see "No such file", maybe do a file exists check right before `batchGateway.upload(test)`

Comment: So this file `'/home/demo/sftp/foo.txt'` exists? Then try to `chmod 777` it just to test

Comment: @Hantsy, have you resolved the issue? I am facing the same issue

Comment: @Sriram used an embeded sftp instead.https://github.com/hantsy/spring-puzzles/blob/master/integration-sftp/src/test/kotlin/com/example/demo/EmbeddedSftpServer.kt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not find a solution to make it work via Docker compose file.

Finally,I added apache sshd into dependencies and prepared an `EmbeddSftpServer` instead.

```kotlin
class EmbeddedSftpServer : InitializingBean, SmartLifecycle {
    private val server = SshServer.setUpDefaultServer()

    @Volatile
    private var port = 0

    @Volatile
    private var homeFolder: Path? = null

    @Volatile
    private var running = false

    fun setPort(port: Int) {
        this.port = port
    }

    fun setHomeFolder(path: Path) {
        this.homeFolder = path
    }

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun afterPropertiesSet() {
        val allowedKey: PublicKey = decodePublicKey()
        server.publickeyAuthenticator =
            PublickeyAuthenticator { username: String?, key: PublicKey, session: ServerSession? ->
                key == allowedKey
            }
        server.port = port
        server.keyPairProvider = SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider(Files.createTempFile("host_file", ".ser"))
        server.subsystemFactories = Collections.singletonList(SftpSubsystemFactory())
        server.fileSystemFactory = if (this.homeFolder != null) {
            VirtualFileSystemFactory(this.homeFolder)
        } else {
            VirtualFileSystemFactory(Files.createTempDirectory("SFTP_TEMP"))
        }
        //server.commandFactory = ScpCommandFactory()
    }

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    private fun decodePublicKey(): PublicKey {
        val stream: InputStream = ClassPathResource("META-INF/keys/sftp_rsa.pub").inputStream
        var keyBytes: ByteArray = StreamUtils.copyToByteArray(stream)
        // strip any newline chars
        while (keyBytes[keyBytes.size - 1].toInt() == 0x0a || keyBytes[keyBytes.size - 1].toInt() == 0x0d) {
            keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(keyBytes, keyBytes.size - 1)
        }
        val decodeBuffer: ByteArray = Base64.getDecoder().decode(keyBytes)
        val bb: ByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(decodeBuffer)
        val len: Int = bb.int
        val type = ByteArray(len)
        bb.get(type)
        return if ("ssh-rsa" == String(type)) {
            val e: BigInteger = decodeBigInt(bb)
            val m: BigInteger = decodeBigInt(bb)
            val spec = RSAPublicKeySpec(m, e)
            KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(spec)
        } else {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Only supports RSA")
        }
    }

    private fun decodeBigInt(bb: ByteBuffer): BigInteger {
        val len: Int = bb.int
        val bytes = ByteArray(len)
        bb.get(bytes)
        return BigInteger(bytes)
    }

    override fun isAutoStartup(): Boolean {
        return PORT == port
    }

    override fun getPhase(): Int {
        return Int.MAX_VALUE
    }

    override fun start() {
        try {
            server.start()
            running = true
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            throw IllegalStateException(e)
        }
    }

    override fun stop(callback: Runnable) {
        stop()
        callback.run()
    }

    override fun stop() {
        if (running) {
            try {
                server.stop(true)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                throw IllegalStateException(e)
            } finally {
                running = false
            }
        }
    }

    override fun isRunning(): Boolean {
        return running
    }

    companion object {
        /**
         * Let OS to obtain the proper port
         */
        const val PORT = 0
    }
}
```

And declare it as bean in the test, https://github.com/hantsy/spring-puzzles/blob/master/integration-sftp/src/test/kotlin/com/example/demo/SftpIntegrationFlowsTestWithEmbeddedSftpServer.kt#L65

Check the complete example project here, https://github.com/hantsy/spring-puzzles/blob/master/integration-sftp

Answer (score 0):

Works to me (make sure the path of target file to upload is correct):

```
public static DefaultSftpSessionFactory sftpSessionFactory() {
    DefaultSftpSessionFactory sessionFactory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory();
    sessionFactory.setHost("hostip");
    sessionFactory.setPort(65002); //might be 22 as well
    sessionFactory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
    sessionFactory.setUser("user");
    sessionFactory.setPassword("pass");

    return sessionFactory;
}

public static void upload() throws IOException {
    SftpSession session = sftpSessionFactory().getSession();
    InputStream fileStream = YourClassName.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("path_to_local_file/test.txt");
    session.write(fileStream, "path_to_remote/test.txt");

    session.close();
}
```

Comment: My issue is specific when using a sftp in Docker, for the Sftp in local system, it works well.